# runnable JAR: local path issue

Tags: file, jar, path, local, runnable

I want to export my project to a runnable JAR (in Eclipse). But I have a Code-Section with a local path!  How can I avoid the local path problem?

Thank you very much for helping me.

```
static {
    URL url = null;
    WebServiceException e = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("file:/C:/myWorkspace/myProject/folder/data.wsdl");
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        e = new WebServiceException(ex);
    }
    APISERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    APISERVICE_EXCEPTION = e;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple. Use a relative path URL. It is always a better practice to keep your files under src/main/resources directory and access via `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream()`

Comment: How can I do it in the following case: @WebServiceClient(name = "", targetNamespace = "", wsdlLocation = "src/a/data.wsdl")
public class CLassName{.....}

Comment: src is the path where Java runs. So you can access it using URL url = new URL(new URL("file:"), "a/data.wsdl");